# Build and build on

Tags: word-usage

Can we use verb 'build' and phrasal verb 'build on' interchangeably? For example - I have to build /build on my  credit rating for becoming eligible for a home loan.
Will it (interchangeability of verb and phrasal verb) applicable to following verb also? 
"decide and decide on"

Answer (score 3):

Not really.

*Build X* can lean towards meaning X doesn't exist yet and you are going to construct X.

*Build on X* means you are doing new things to enhance or evolve X.

*Build up X* can phrasally mean "obtain a supply of X for later."

The *on* in *decide on* isn't really a phrasal variation.  *On X* can be used if X is a topic/purpose/point of a conversation, meeting, etc.

Comment: Based on your answer there is a big difference between "**to build up your strength**" and "**to build on your strength**".

Comment: Thank you Lawrence for your guidance.So,do the following sentences imply the point you have made?                                                                                      The teacher hasn't yet decided which topic to be taken up next.                         The teacher decided on the date of examination.

Comment: Some examples in your answer would be helpful. Also you should explain "Not really".

Comment: There is also *build upon*, which like *build on* suggests adding that a foundation has already been laid. *Build out* is related as well, though more for physical construction and metaphors relating to it (like *building out* a software library).